# Breakpoints don't work when debugging dart web-ui app

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

I'm trying to debug application which uses web-ui.
App runs correctly but doesn't stop on breakpoints.
I tried to set them in both *.dart files, one in web folder and the other one in web/out folder.
I'm using  0.5.20.4_r24275 version

Comment: are you using an URL launch by chance? iirc there is an open bug about this.

Comment: I tried both URL launch and usual with no difference

Comment: It's also the same with the newly generated app. I create new application with choosing to generate sample content (Web application(using the web_ui library)). Run it in dartium, breakpoints don't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue. I was going do some live code demo for my co-workers and wanted to show off the powerful debugging possible with this nicely structured language. Hoping for quick fix!  I run 64bit windows 7 and have the same version (0.5.20_r24275)